# Vector Indexing using Logical vector

Tags: r, object, vector, logical-operators, rgui

I am new to R. I have created an object a:
`a <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)`

I have performed the following operation on the vector:
`a[!c(10,0,8,6,0)]`
and I get the output as 4 10 14 20

I do understand that `!c(10,0,8,6,0)` produces the output as FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

I don't understand how the final results comes out to be 4 10 14 20

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

We obtain the results because the logical vector is recycled (as its length is only 5 compared to `length(a)` which is 10) to meet the end of the 'a' vector i..e

```
i1 <- rep(!c(10,0,8,6,0), length.out = length(a))
i1
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If we use that vector

```
a[i1]
[1]  4 10 14 20
```

It is easier to understand if we just pass `TRUE`, then the TRUE is recycled to return all the elements or the reverse with `FALSE`

```
a[TRUE]
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
a[FALSE]
numeric(0)
```

The recycling is mentioned in the documentation of `?Extract`

> For [-indexing only: i, j, ... can be logical vectors, indicating elements/slices to select. Such vectors are recycled if necessary to match the corresponding extent. i, j, ... can also be negative integers, indicating elements/slices to leave out of the selection.

---

In most of the languages, 0 is considered as FALSE and other values as TRUE. So, when we negate the 0 (FALSE) is converted to TRUE and all others to FALSE